# How to know what is taking up the most size of my swf with the help of flex profiling?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3

[image]

Now the size of my flex swf is **480KB** and I'm trying to find a way to reduce its size,are there any tips to follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Flex Framework takes somewhere between 250-400 KB of swf file (depending on version, debug/release compilation and how many components you use) so it might be the problem here. It's not possible to make a flex app which takes let's say 10 KB (if you use RSL your users still HAVE to download it anyway).